# Formula that depends on value within a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a cost of sales table, and depending on the order size
I need to select the right number of packaging items. 
So, for example, if I sell ≤ 20, then the packaging needed is 1 (item);
if I sell between 21 and 40 then I need 2 (items); 
41-60 is 3; 61-80 is 4 and 81-100 is 5. 
That's as far as I need to go. 
I can then calculate out the *cost* of the packaging,
but I'm struggling with the logic needed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: All resolved...the nested IF solution worked perfectly.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I presume that an order of 20 requires 1 (one) package
and an order of 80 requires 4 (four) packages. 
If those are your numbers,
then

```
=ROUNDUP(order_size/20, 0)
```

should work. 
So, for example, if the order size is in cell `A1`, you would use

```
=ROUNDUP(A1/20, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested IF formula. Also, your description above doesn't include how to treat the exact value of "20". You have < 20 for 1 package, then 21-40 for 2 packages. Adjust the first value as needed.

Cell B2 formula:

```
    =IF(A2<20,1,IF(A2<41,2,IF(A2<61,3,IF(A2<81,4,5))))
```

Drag it down, done.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like it's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use MATCHE to return the relative position in the array:

```
=MATCH(A2,{0,20,41,61,81})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like there's a couple of ways to achieve the result.  I'll try anything and everything..!